# Why did Riker and Worf not react to learning about Lore in Descent Part 2

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

At the end of Season 6 of *TNG*, ["Descent Part 1"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Descent_(episode)) concludes with the discovery by Picard, Troi and LaForge that Lore is alive and in control of the Borg Collective (or at least part of it). They are immediately captured by Lore and the Borg without ever getting a chance to communicate with anyone else.

In the Season 7 premiere, Hugh tells Riker and Worf that Lore is in control of the Borg. But Riker and Worf react like they already knew this, even though they had no way of knowing it.  Did I miss something, or is this just a plot hole?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The intention was that Hugh had explained the situation with Lore to Worf and Riker offscreen, in between Act Two and Act Three (i.e. during the commercial break). From the [Descent Part II script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/253.txt) on [this website](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/):

> RIKER
>
> Hugh... ?
>
> But Hugh has changed from the last time Riker and Worf saw him. He
>   does not welcome them; his words are tinged with bitterness and
>   confrontation.
>
> HUGH Why are you here, Commander Riker? Hasn't the crew of the
>   Enterprise caused enough damage already?
>
> Off Riker and Worf's surprise...
>
> FADE OUT.
>
> **END OF ACT TWO**
>
> STAR TREK: "Descent, Part II" - REV. 6/24/93 - ACT THREE  28.
>
> **ACT THREE**
>
> FADE IN:
>
> 29   INT. UNDERGROUND CAVERNS
>
> Riker, Worf, and Hugh have moved to another part of the chamber and
>   are talking. **Hugh has explained Lore's takeover of the Borg,** and his
>   take on it does not sit right with Worf.
>
> WORF You blame us -- for what has happened to the Borg?

If you watch the episode on DVD or blu ray, you can see there is a dramatic musical cue followed by a fade to black after Hugh's line "hasn't the crew of the Enterprise caused enough damage already?", indicating that a commercial break would have gone there. People who do most of their TV watching on DVD or streaming may forget these conventions, but back when these shows were mostly seen on TV with commercials, I think it tended to be understood by audiences that when there was a new scene after a commercial break, several minutes or even longer might have passed since the last scene in-universe, including updating characters on things the audience already knew.

Comment: Nice work, @Hypnosifl!  It's always good to check the *original* scripts. +1

Comment: Good catch.  I was a little distracted and completely missed the cut. Actually, I must have been a lot distracted because Hulu even went to a commercial at that cut.